Find smallest natural number $n$ such that, $\sin(n+80)+\sin(n-40)+\sin(n+70)=\cos(25)$
Find the smallest natural number $n$ such that, $$\sin(n+80)+\sin(n-40)+\sin(n+70)=\cos(25)$$  here all angles are measured in degrees.
My attempt: I tried converting them the angles to an A.P. but was unable to process. Secondly, I converted the expression using sum to product trigonometric identity after which I was unable to proceed.$$\sin(n+20)+\sin(n+70)=\cos(25)$$

Next time please write \sin and \cos

$$\sin(n+20^\circ)+\sin(n+70^\circ)=2\sin(n+45^\circ)\cos25^\circ$$

You are going right , my friend!
$\sin(n+20)+\sin(n+70)=\cos(25)$
Now using the formula when angles are in A.P. we will get,
$$\frac{\sin(2*50/2)}{\sin(50/2)}*\sin\left(\frac{(n+20)+(n+70)}{2}\right)=\cos(25)$$
On further calculation we will get
$$ \sin(50)*\sin(n+45)=\cos(25)\sin(25)$$
$$ \sin(50)*\sin(n+45)=\frac{2*\cos(25)\sin(25)}{2}$$
$$ \sin(50)*\sin(n+45)=\frac{\sin(50)}{2}$$
$$ \sin(n+45)=\frac{1}{2}$$
Now you can easily get $n=105$
